# How to check if id exist in CodeIgniter Cart?

Tags: codeigniter, insert, shopping-cart

Is there way to check if ID exist in CI Chart, and just upadte quantity, of that product, if not add new item?

This is what i have so far, but nothing is working :(

```
if (isset($_POST['sendorder']))
{
$qty=$_POST['productquantity'];

$data = array(
           'id'      => $id,
               'qty'     => $qty,
               'price'   => $price,
               'name'    => $heading
            );


if (count($this->cart->contents())>0){
                    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item){
                        if ($item['id']==$id){
                            $data = array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],
                            'qty'=>++$item['qty']);
                            $this->cart->update($data);

                        }
            else{
                          $this->cart->insert($data);
                            }
                    }   

}
}
```

Comment: try **var_dump($this->cart);** somewhere and see what is inside ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    // set $flag default value to true for inserting item to the cart session
    $insert_new = TRUE;
    $bag = $this->cart->contents();

    foreach ($bag as $item) {

        // check product id in session, if exist update the quantity
        if ( $item['id'] == '1' ) { // Set value to your variable

            $data = array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],'qty'=>++$item['qty']);
            $this->cart->update($data);

            // set $insert_new value to False
            $insert_new = FALSE;

        }

    }

    // if $insert_new value is true, insert the item as new item in the cart
    if ($insert_new) {
        $data = array(
                'id' => 1,
                'qty' => 1,
                'price' => 40,
                'name' => 'Product item'
            );
        $this->cart->insert($data);

    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your changes a little to help make a better quality answer?